# Нужно вывести случайно сгенерированое число с помощью innerHTML

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код который генерирует число и это число сохраняется  в переменой и мне это сгенеривованое число нужно вывести с помощью innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var peremennaja = Math.random();
  var element = document.getElementById("test");
  element.innerHTML = peremennaja;
});
```

```html
<span id="test"></span>
```

Comment: Вот то и суть что таким образом не выводит

Comment: @ЕвгенийКраев Хотите, я расскажу Вам про телепатов?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКраев Скрипт должен быть размещен в коде после HTML-блока с этим id. Или в виде `<script src="..." defer></script>`